# Android - callback if DialogFragment is closes in another DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

There is a DialogFragment `DialogA` and on top of this there is another DialogFragment `DialogB`. If `DialogB` is closed there should be an event fired on `DialogA`, so that the view can be refreshed (no matter if "YES", "CANCEL" or Back was pressed).

How is it possible to get the closing event of `DialogB`?

I tried it with BroadcastReceiver and with overriding onResume. But none of them is fired if `DialogB` is closed.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Did u try with `setOnDismissListener` for dialog?

Comment: check eventbus it will help you in receiving events. http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a public method in Dialog A and on button click of YES OR NO whatever it is, Call that method and close the dialog B.

Comment: I don't have access to DialogA in DialogB. They are independant classes and not nested.

Comment: If it's independent class, you can create an object of A in B and then call that method using that object.